2 NICs, PC is trying to use wrong one
Ubuntu 24 server, 2 NICs, one is usual LAN/WAN to Internet, other is flat 10.1.1.* network of cameras and dumb switches with no routing or gateway (the server is a security video system running ZoneMinder). My server seems to be confused about how to get to Internet addresses, and it is trying to route to addresses other than 10.1.1.* via the NIC that has no gateway or router.
NIC1 - enp1s0 - 10.1.1.115, nothing but 10.1.1.* addresses (10.1.1.100 is DHCP/NTP server for the cameras)
NIC2 - enp0s31f6 - 192.168.1.249, gateway is 192.168.1.1, rest of the world
My logs appear to indicate that the machine is trying to route to a remote external client like 12.75.125.XXX via NIC1, and the remote external client is timing out waiting. The log entries I'm fretting over are, for example:
2024-09-28T13:17:35.321463-04:00 servername kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=enp1s0 SRC=192.168.1.249 DST=12.75.126.XXX LEN=1500 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=18563 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=64883 WINDOW=505 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
2024-09-28T13:17:34.731460-04:00 servername kernel: [UFW AUDIT] IN= OUT=enp1s0 SRC=192.168.1.249 DST=12.75.126.XXX LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=18562 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=443 DPT=64883 WINDOW=505 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0

ip route shows:
default via 10.1.1.100 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp src 10.1.1.115 metric 100
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.249 metric 100 
10.1.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.115 metric 100 
10.1.1.100 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.1.115 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.249 metric 100 
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.249 metric 100

Is the route table the problem? I don't know how to fix this frustrating problem.
After attempting to fix the DHCP issue, ip a shows:
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a8:42:a1:06:23:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.1.1.115/24 metric 100 brd 10.1.1.255 scope global dynamic enp1s0
       valid_lft 2675237sec preferred_lft 2675237sec
    inet6 fe80::aa42:a1ff:fe06:2346/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 54:bf:64:76:e4:af brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.249/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic enp0s31f6
       valid_lft 82280sec preferred_lft 82280sec
    inet6 2605:8600:5c0:a4fe:56bf:64ff:fe76:e4af/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 70696sec preferred_lft 49096sec
    inet6 fe80::56bf:64ff:fe76:e4af/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

I found a typo in the DHCP.conf (10.1.1.100 is the DHCP server, it's a Ubuntu 18 box). It had a router option that I commented out. I restarted the webserver and the DHCP server, and ... this seems to have fixed my problem of external clients being unable to access the webserver.  ip route shows:
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp src 192.168.1.249 metric 100 
10.1.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.1.115 metric 100 
10.1.1.100 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.1.115 metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp0s31f6 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.249 metric 100 
192.168.1.1 dev enp0s31f6 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.1.249 metric 100 

So I think I'm back in business. But someone suggested I should change the "metric" value? I want all 10.1.1.X going out NIC1 and everything else going out NIC2, what should I do with the metric settings to further optimize?

2 questions - what are the NICs in question, specifically what speed are they , and if you're using netplan can you set a metric? https://superuser.com/a/1847910/10165 is an example. You want to set a lower metric for the preferred route.

@JourneymanGeek there's no need for a metric, there is no "preferred route", there is only one route for each possible destination. One interface for 10.1.1.0/24 and the other interface for all there rest.

Your routing table shows that there is default gateway 10.1.1.100 defined for NIC1. This is the cause of the problem. There should be no default gateway defined at all for this network.
Seems like your DHCP server for this network is configured so that it defines itself as the default gateway. You should reconfigure it so that it defines no default gateway at all.

Makes me wonder what the device with 10.1.1.100 is in OP's network - if its another manageable device, the DHCP server should stop offering itself as the gateway.

Alternatively, every DHCP client that I know of allows specifying a "metric" for DHCP-advertised routing rules. As long as you configure the metric for NIC1 to be (numerically) larger than that for NIC2, it won't be picked up by the OS.
For example, with systemd-networkd, this is what you need:
# /etc/systemd/network/whatever-nic1.network
[DHCPv4]
RouteMetric=200

